# Why does sql server have a hard time rounding floats?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
    if exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'd_ratio') begin drop table d_ratio end
    if exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'elrd') begin drop table elrd end

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[d_ratio](
        [index] [bigint] NULL,
        [Class] [bigint] NULL,
        [Dratio] [float] NULL,
        [ELR-Act1] [float] NULL,
        [ELR-Act2] [float] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    Insert into D_ratio
    select 0,2503,0.285,0.75,1.33

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ELRD](
        [RATE_EFFDT] [date] NOT NULL,
        [CLASS] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
        [ELR] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
        [D_RATIO] [decimal](5, 2) NULL,
        [EXPO_ACT] [char](2) NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    truncate table elrd
    insert into elrd(Rate_effdt, class, elr, d_ratio, EXPO_ACT)
    select getdate(), right('0000' + cast(class as varchar(10)),4), round(cast([ELR-Act1] as decimal(10,3)),2),Dratio, 1
    from d_ratio

    select Dratio, * from d_ratio
    select D_ratio, * from elrd
```

It goes in as 0.285 and comes out as 0.28.

However if I cast it as a decimal with 3 points of precision like so:

```
    truncate table elrd
    insert into elrd(Rate_effdt, class, elr, d_ratio, EXPO_ACT)
    select getdate(), right('0000' + cast(class as varchar(10)),4), round(cast([ELR-Act1] as decimal(10,3)),2), cast(dratio as decimal(10,3)), 1
    from d_ratio
```

It goes in as 0.285 and comes out as 0.29 - it gets rounded properly.

**Question** What is SQL Server doing? Is it truncating floats and rounding decimals?

Comment: Have you considered just using decimal (which rounds as you expect) instead of float (which does not)? The behavior differences are documented in the standard, but as a peer offering advice I would simply recommend using the type that works and not using the one that doesn't.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I can - I'm importing it from excel, so it is coming in as float. I suppose I could cast it on the initial import process.

Comment: You're importing it from Excel into a table, right? That table can be defined with decimal columns, not float columns.

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the SQL Server manual, it appears that the database is using an IEEE `float` under the hood.

As such, "weird things" are known to happen.

See this FAQ from SQLite (I suspect it applies here also):

[(16) Why does ROUND(9.95,1) return 9.9 instead of 10.0? Shouldn't 9.95 round up?](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q16)